# How to tag new version of an image, when deploying to ECR on AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, amazon-ecr

I wanted to run my docker image in AWS Fargate, so I followed this simple [tutorial](https://medium.com/faun/deploying-docker-images-to-ecs-b43058dc0456). Basically, I created an image on my computer and pushed it to the ECR. The tutorial (and AWS "Push commands" cheat sheet as well) suggests to tag the image as ***latest***.

So I did, I tagged it as "latest", I pushed it to ECR, I created the Cluster and Task and successfully run this image in Fargate. But now I'm confused, because I fixed something in my image and would like to deploy new version. How should I tag the new image?

Should I rename the previous image, and the new one should be "latest" again? All tutorial I found a teaching how to deploy first image to the ECR. But I can't find anything that would show how to deploy new versions?

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to rename the previous image, though you should if you want to keep it. Tagging something as `latest` when there is another image that is `latest` will replace the old image with the new. Any new instances of you task in ECS will pick up the new image, but ECS will not automatically replace existing tasks. You have to manually do that (obviously you can do it programmatically).

Please keep in mind that tutorials like this are not always designed for production workloads. They are designed to get you working. This is not the best way to manage ECS task updates.

Comment: thanks Jason, I'm aware, I'm trying to take one step at the time. So, I need to create new task and remove the old task?

Comment: If you stop the old task a new one will be started automatically, to replace it, assuming you have the service set to have one task.

Comment: No, I have just a task. I assume for production it would make more sense to create a service instead of just a task. Is that right ?

Comment: Yes. In production I would create services for your tasks. The service give you a place to manage things like auto-scaling as well.